# Use stanford core nlp lemmatization with romanian language?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

Is there any way to use [stanford core-nlp](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html) with a romanian language model?
It looks like it doesnt have the romanian language in the core library but I have tried to download the language model from the python library: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/models.html and somehow import them into the java code (`props.setProperty("pos.model","PATH...")` but they dont seem to be compatible, it gives the erorr `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:`.

If using core-nlp is not possible are you aware of any java lemmatization library that supports romanian?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms, data structures, and model files of CoreNLP and Stanza (formerly stanfordnlp) are completely different. There isn't, and there isn't likely to ever be, any means of moving models between them in either direction.

The only thing I know of is that the Snowball stemmer supports Romanian and is usable in Java, if that's sufficient:

- https://github.com/snowballstem
- https://snowballstem.org/algorithms/